# SQL select MAX from other table

Tags: mysql

I have two tables.

#### table1:

```
| ID | NAME |
|----|------|
| 1  | aaa  |
| 2  | aaa  |
| 3  | aaa  |
| 4  | bbb  |
| 5  | bbb  |
```

#### table2:

```
| ID | DATE     |
|----|----------|
| 1  | 12/07/10 |
| 2  | 12/07/13 |
| 3  | 12/07/16 |
| 4  | 12/07/08 |
| 5  | 12/07/20 |
```

Help me pls, I don't know how to **`SELECT MAX ID` in `table1`** by **`date` in `table2`**.

For example result should be:

> for "aaa": ID 3 from table2
>
> for "bbb": ID 5 from table2

I'm trying something like that:

```
DATE = (SELECT MAX(DATE) FROM table2 t2, table1 t1 WHERE t1.NAME = "aaa")
```

But it's not working... Have you got some idea?

Comment: Provide with the clear table structure since it is bit confusing:) If you provide with a better display of the table and question it is very easy to solve your request.

Comment: What's the relationship between these two tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add an additional condition (`t1.id = t2.id`) for the join:

```
SELECT MAX(DATE) 
FROM table2 t2, table1 t1 
WHERE t1.NAME = "aaa"
  AND t1.id = t2.id
```

But please - don't join with comma - use explicit JOIN syntax instead:

```
SELECT MAX(DATE) 
FROM table2 t2
JOIN table1 t1 
  ON t1.id = t2.id
WHERE t1.NAME = "aaa"
```

You can also get all max dates for all names at once using `GROUP BY name`:

```
SELECT t1.NAME, MAX(t2.DATE) 
FROM table2 t2
JOIN table1 t1 
  ON t1.id = t2.id
GROUP BY t1.NAME
```

Answer (score 0):

> I have tried to take the MAX Date using this query.
>
> **Note:** In the table the date format should be (Y-m-d) and the field should be set to date in order to manipulate the operations

**Table - 1**(Name: test1)

[image]

**Table - 2**(Name: test2)

[image]

> QUERY TO GET MAX FROM OTHER TABLE

```
SELECT MAX(dates) FROM test2 JOIN test1 WHERE test1.name='aaa'
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Hope so this query will solve your problem.

Comment: This is wrong. For "aaa" result should be 2016-08-04

Comment: Then how so you need the Output.. You have to generate it dynamically or what. :)

Comment: From your tables: 
for "aaa" result should be 2016-08-04
for "bbb" result should be 2016-08-11

Comment: One doubt. You have to take the Max Value from Second Table according to count from the first table values. Have i understood correct :)

Comment: Yes. How can I output Max Value from second table according id from first table? 
So for name "aaa" output should be 2016-08-04
name "bbb" outpu should be 2016-08-11

Answer (score 0):

```
select ID from Table1 where date= (select max(date) from T2 where name= 'aaa'
```

i didn't fully got you. But I think this is how you want it.... If you had these two table as one table then it would work as charm.

Or THIS ,with Two Table like you asked for

```
SELECT T1.Id FROM T1 INNER JOIN T2 
ON T1.Id = T2.Id 
where T2.date = (select max(T2.date) from T1 where T1.name= 'aaa')
```